# isolcpus - binding not working

Tags: linux, multithreading, cpu-usage, cpuset

Sorry, this is a duplicate question from ServerFault. I am posting this here since I didn't get any response there.

Question:

I am using isolcpus to isolate cores. I would like to bind specific threads to cores, but it is not working. The threads are moved to different cores after I bind them.

Cores 13, 14, and 15 are isolated:

```
$ cat /proc/cmdline
ro root=/dev/mapper/vg0-root rd_NO_LUKS LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_LVM_LV=vg0/swaprd_NO_MD SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=137M@0M rd_NO_DM  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rd_LVM_LV=vg0/root rhgb quiet audit=0 intel_idle.max_cstate=0 console=tty0 console=ttyS1,115200 printk.time=1 processor.max_cstate=1 idle=poll biosdevname=0  isolcpus=13-15
```

top -H -p `pgrep -u prusr12 Ser` -d 1 shows this: 5017 and 5018 should have been bound to 14 and 15 and 5014 and 5016 should have been on 13.

```
PID  USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+   P COMMAND
5017 prusr12   20   0 1312m 1.1g 1.1g R 99.9  0.9   9:53.93  5 Server-3.10.
5018 prusr12   20   0 1312m 1.1g 1.1g R 99.9  0.9  10:08.88  7 Server-3.10.
5014 prusr12   20   0 1312m 1.1g 1.1g S  0.0  0.9   0:00.40  2 Server-3.10.
5016 prusr12   20   0 1312m 1.1g 1.1g S  0.0  0.9   0:01.04  4 Server-3.10.
```

The command line is this:

```
sg devuser "taskset -c 13 /releases/3.10.0/bin/Server-3.10.0 -n X -e DEV -p DEFAULT > /logs/ServerDevPR_DEFAULT.out 2>&1 &"
```

There are 4 threads in the process. I want the main thread to start on 13, hence taskset -c 13. Then two threads are spawed and will bind them to 14 and 15. I see that the threads were bound to 14 and 15, but then they were moved to other cores. pthread_setaffinity_np() is being used to bind the threads to cores.

Log after I bind the threads to 14 and 15:
CpuSet returned by pthread_getaffinity_np() contained:CPU 14
CpuSet returned by pthread_getaffinity_np() contained:CPU 15

System details:

```
$ uname -a
Linux host123 2.6.32-573.12.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Nov 23 12:55:32 EST 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                16
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-15
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    8
Socket(s):             2
NUMA node(s):          2
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 63
Stepping:              2
CPU MHz:               3199.847
BogoMIPS:              6399.06
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              20480K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7
NUMA node1 CPU(s):     8-15
```

What could be going wrong? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Do you check the return value from `pthread_setaffinity_np()` ? Can you verify that `pthread_getaffinity_np()` returns correct value?

Comment: I checked both and they are correct.